# Manage members of the OG_Sync Access Control Group

Tags: acl

We are using Drupal Organic Groups, and the OG_Sync function that ships with CiviCRM Core to create corresponding CiviCRM Groups.  We are converting from an existing system where all editing is carried out by a central team (not using OG) to an OG-based system with distributed editors, and need to manage the transition, possibly over a considerable period.  We would like to be able to:

1. Disassociate the OG GroupManager role from the Author of the Group page (currently the Author is automatically the GroupManager).
2. OR ignore the GroupManager Role and set up another OG Role which has the same privileges (in particular to use CiviCRM Email to Group members), and is automatically sync'ed with the CiviCRM Access Control Group for that purpose - in the same way that Group Manager is at present.
3. Allow for more than one User/Contact to be automatically sync'ed with the Access Control Group - probably falls out of item 2.

Can anyone suggest a way forward on this?

With thanks, Tony

Comment: Can you flesh out more about the logic/characteristics in civi of the folk who you want to be OG Managers and OG Members? We have done various tricks to run OG off Events and off Relationships so wondering if there is some overlap.

Comment: We are a community organisation structured as various interest groups of people who meet to do a variety of leisure activities.  We are using CiviCRM Contacts and Membership as the membership system for the organisation as a whole and want to use OG to give each interest group a web page and details of associated activities, and also its own list of subscribers and and emailing facilities.  As I mention this is a conversion from an existing straightforward Drupal website.  We will probably utilise CiviCRM Events to provide booking facilities, but we haven't started to work on that yet.